# Lumen 5.5 NotFoundHttpException handler

Tags: php, http, lumen

I'm running a small app on Lumen 5.5 and in my error handler, when I pass in a view as the content of my response, the headers get an error 500 instead of 404.

I've added a sample snippet, please consider I would only return one or the other response !

File : app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function render($request, Exception $e) {
    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {

        // This gives me a 404 in the browser dev console but not in the headers
        return response(view("errors.404"), 404);

        // This gives me a 404 in the headers
        return response('404 error', 404);

    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

If I load this page in the browser DevTools, my GET has a status of 404, but if I scan with http checker tools online I get an error 500.

This is messing with my Adwords campaign so I had to switch for a plain response.

Since it's Lumen, I can't use the following that would work in Laravel :

```
return response(view('error.404', [], 404));
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Views were removed from Lumen a couple point versions ago. I think there may be way to add them by adding code to some config files, but it appears views are no longer considered to be part of the project.

Comment: Ok thank you. I moved from Lumen to Laravel for the next projects, I wasn't using the good tools for the job.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
    return new Response(
        view('errors.404'),
        $e->getStatusCode(),
        $e->getHeaders()
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The headers are still 500 error via every http status tools online, but my own browser gives me a 404 error. I simply ditched the template rendering, since it was a small landing page with a short lifespan.